# Project-Specific Eclipse Python Interpreters

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Is it possible to have project-specific Python interpreters in Eclipse? I have some projects running in virtual environments via `venv` and would like to be able to debug (using `PyDev`) but the interpreter list seems to only be global.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have project-specific interpreters in Eclipse...

The process is: load it at the Python interpreter in the preferences page (as usual) and double-click to give it some better name as that name will later be stored at the project.

Then go to the `project properties > PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar` and select to which interpreter the project should be bound to.

Now, whenever you run some module from that project, that should be the interpreter used to do the run.

Another option (if you only want to run with a different interpreter once) would be changing the interpreter only for a given launch in the run configuration.